# Auto Login sometimes fails and requires a password

Tags: login, password

I am setting up some old laptops with Ubuntu 14.04 for students in kindergarten through 3rd grade.  I want to have them boot automatically into Ubuntu with a username of egpl  I do NOT want to require a password as many cannot type at this point.  So I have set up a Standard User - Username egpl - Autologin set to yes and password is NONE

Unfortunately, Ubuntu will sometimes stop at the login screen and ask for a password for egpl but then when I hit enter it says the password is incorrect.  Most of the answers I have seen about plymouth, etc are for version 12.04 and fail when I attempt them.  Please help!

Comment: This looks like a bug that has already been reported.See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1250875 and register yourself as being affected by the bug.

Comment: Thanks user68186!  I had looked through the bug reports but I am new to Ubuntu and didn't know what lightdm was so I didn't think it applied.  Now I have to figure out how to let them know that I am affected too.  Thanks again!

Comment: First, you login by clicking on the login line at the right top edge of the bug report screen. Log in using the same credentials you use to log into Ask Ubuntu. Then you will see "This bug affects N people, does this affect you?" in green right above the word **Affects**. Click on the question and you will be on set.